# get content of some tags inside a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sugarcrm, suitecrm

```
var a = $('#txta').val();
console.log(a);
```

result is complete html code from [this](http://online.dis.rs/proizvodi.php?limit=0) url

Now I want to get content of all `#artikal-naziv` tags (there are 96)

```
var b = a.find("#artikal-naziv").text();
console.log(b);
```

Result:

`Uncaught TypeError: a.find is not a function`

Any help?

Comment: $(a).find("#artikal-naziv").text(); should do the trick. But dont ever use an ID multiple times in a html.

Comment: also post the html source code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*.val()* takes out the value from the element....**Whereas** all DOM operations are done on the element... because function like .find() , .hide() , .show() , .closest() etc are used with the element *not the value*

The Following modifications should work...

```
var a = $('#txta'); // $("#ID") returns the element
console.log(a.val()); // $("#ID").val() returns the value
```

the result is complete html code from this URL

Now I want to get content of all #artikal-naziv tags (there are 96)

```
var b = a.find("#artikal-naziv").text(); // .find() easily works on element
console.log(b);
```

Comment: `console.log(b)` returns nothing, just empty line. But there are 96 `artikal-naziv` tags inside `#txta`?

Comment: `http://online.dis.rs/proizvodi.php?limit=0` - go to html source and you will see

Comment: i dint find any element with **#txta** or **#artikal-naziv** :(

Comment: go to Ctrl F (find) - you will find 96 instances of this - `<div id="artikal-naziv">`

Answer (score 3):

Actually you are calling `.find()` on a `string` and not in a DOM element.

Because from `$('#txta').val()` you are getting a `string`, that's why you got `Uncaught TypeError: a.find is not a function`, because `string` doesn't have `.find()` method.

You should change it to:

```
var a = $('#txta');
```

Then you can write:

```
var b = a.find("#artikal-naziv").text();
```

**Note:**

> Now I want to get content of all #artikal-naziv tags (there are 96)

You can't set the same id `#artikal-naziv` for multiple elements (96), the `id` should be unique in the page.

Another thing **[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** call assumes that your element is a form element, you can't call `.val()` on a `div` or a `span`, if it isn't a form element use **[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** instead.

Comment: Not sure if this is what OP is looking for.

Comment: Yes me too, none is sure about what the OP needs. It's far to be clear in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Because "a" is not a jQuery object - it's usually a string containing value of the returned element (txta).

Use `$(a).find(...)` instead - that will probably do it.

Ref link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3532381/3704489

Answer (score 2):

As per what I can make out of your description, you are getting HTML as string using `var a = $('#txta').val();`. If this is true, you will have to create an in-memory element and set this string as its HTML.

Then you will have an in-memory DOM section that you can query on.

You can try something like this:

```js
var html = '<span><p id="artikal-naziv">bla bla</p></span>';

var $tempElement = $('<div>').html(html);
console.log($tempElement.find('#artikal-naziv').text());
// or using vanilla JS

var tempElement = document.createElement('div');
tempElement.innerHTML = html;

console.log(tempElement.querySelector('#artikal-naziv').textContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Really!!  Getting the html content in a variable then setting it into a temporary div element, to fetch it?! It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @chsdk when OP said *result is complete html code from this url*, I'm assuming that he/she is getting HTML as string. May be he is creating a compiler or a RTF. But this answer is based on this 1 assumption. Lets wait for OP to confirm if its true. If not, I'll remove answer.

Comment: No offense, but what I tries to mention is that the variable part can be ommited.

Comment: None taken. Its just, this way OP can relate to it and makes it little easy to understand in my POV. Still thanks for pointing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `.find` to find children and `.closest` to find parents:

```
<div class='a'>
    <div class='b'>
        <div class='c'></div>
        <div class='c'></div>
        <div class='c'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var a = $('.b');
a.find('.c'); // Will return all the objects with the class c
a.closest('.a'); // Will return the first parent with the class a
```